# Redhat Codeready Container Failed to start (crc start error): .crcbundle not found

Tags: rhel8, redhat-containers

I am receiving the following error when executing 'crc start -p .\pull-secret.txt' command:

```
/home/admin/.crc/cache/crc_libvirt_4.9.0.crcbundle not found, please provide the path to a valid bundle using the -b option`
```

crc setup --log-level debug` Debug below:

```
INFO Checking if libvirt daemon is running        
DEBU Checking if libvirtd service is running      
DEBU Running 'systemctl status virtqemud.socket'  
DEBU Command failed: exit status 3                
DEBU stdout: * virtqemud.socket - Libvirt qemu local socket
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/virtqemud.socket; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
   Listen: /run/libvirt/virtqemud-sock (Stream) 
DEBU stderr:                                      
DEBU virtqemud.socket is neither running nor listening 
DEBU Running 'systemctl status libvirtd.socket'   
DEBU libvirtd.socket is running  
INFO Checking if systemd-networkd is running      
DEBU Checking if systemd-networkd.service is running 
DEBU Running 'systemctl status systemd-networkd.service' 
DEBU Command failed: exit status 4                
DEBU stdout:                                      
DEBU stderr: Unit systemd-networkd.service could not be found. 
DEBU systemd-networkd.service is not running 
INFO Checking crc daemon systemd service          
DEBU Checking crc daemon systemd service          
DEBU Checking if crc-daemon.service is running    
DEBU Running 'systemctl --user status crc-daemon.service' 
DEBU Command failed: exit status 3                
DEBU stdout: * crc-daemon.service - CodeReady Containers daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/home/admin/.config/systemd/user/crc-daemon.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) 
DEBU stderr:                                      
DEBU crc-daemon.service is neither running nor listening 
DEBU Checking if crc-daemon.service has the expected content 
INFO Checking if systemd-networkd is running      
DEBU Checking if systemd-networkd.service is running 
DEBU Running 'systemctl status systemd-networkd.service' 
DEBU Command failed: exit status 4                
DEBU stdout:                                      
DEBU stderr: Unit systemd-networkd.service could not be found. 
DEBU systemd-networkd.service is not running
```

I then ran the following commands:

```
sudo yan install qemu qemu-kvm libvirt-clients libvirt-daemon-system virtinst bridge-utils
Output:
>> Error: Unable to find a match: qemu libvirt-clients libvirt-daemon-system virtinst bridge-utils
```

```
>> [admin@localhost ~]$ systemctl status libvirtd.service
```

```
- Test systemctl
>> systemctl status libvirtd.service
```

```
crc setup output:

[admin@localhost ~]$ crc setup 
INFO Checking if running as non-root              
INFO Checking if running inside WSL2 
.......... Details removed ..........
INFO Checking if CRC bundle is extracted in '$HOME/.crc' 
Your system is correctly setup for using CodeReady Containers, you can now run 'crc start -b $bundlename' to start the OpenShift cluster
```

I cannot seem to find .crcbundle file despite setup completing successfully.
Nothing found under:

```
#This seems to be an issue as I cannot find '.crcbundle'
[admin@localhost ~]$  tree --noreport .crc
.crc
├── bin
│   ├── crc -> /home/admin/bin/crc
│   ├── crc-admin-helper-linux
│   └── crc-driver-libvirt
├── crc-http.sock
├── crc.json
└── crc.log
```

OS info:

```
REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8"
REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT_VERSION=8.5
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="8.5"
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the problem you should execute the next commands with root user:

- yum install qemu-kvm libvirt libvirt-daemon-kvm
- systemctl start libvirtd
- systemctl enable libvirtd
- systemctl start virtnetworkd
- systemctl enable virtnetworkd
- systemctl start virtstoraged
- systemctl enable virtstoraged

Then you could execute with a non root user session the next commands:

- crc setup
- crc start -p pull-secret.txt